# SQL Server hierarchyid - insert new node between two existing sibling nodes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, hierarchy

Let's say I have a [hierarchyid](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) column in SQL Server (2008 R2).  Let's say I have the following nodes already in the table:

```
/1/
/1/1/
/1/2/
```

I'd like to create an insert statement that inserts between '/1/1/' and '/1/2/', creating node '/1/1.1/'.  However, I don't want to hardcode '/1/1.1/'.  I want to base the insert statement on knowing '/1/1/' and '/1/2/'.  This will be a stored proc so it is okay if some T-SQL is necessary before the insert statement.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  Turns out the answer lies in the GetDescendant method.  Calling this on the parent '/1/', passing '/1/1/' and '/1/2/' as the arguments, returns '/1/1.1/'.